# Detecting and using a changed controller dependency during controller lifetime

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, route-provider

For the sake of understanding suppose I have an AngularJS application that has similar data as Stackoverflow so that it:

1. is using the usual ngRoute/$routeProvider
2. has a `userService` that returns **favourite** and **ignore** tag lists of the logged in user - both lists are fetched at the same time and request for them is a promise that when resolved caches these lists
3. has a view that displays a list of questions with a `QuestionsController` that provides its model (similar to Stackoverflow)
4. `QuestionsController` makes a request for questions and then depends on cached tag lists to mark them appropriately

As the [recommended guideline](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#style-y081) when controllers rely on other async data we should offload those to route `resolve` part so when controllers are being instantiated those promises are already resolved. Therefore I offload tag list fetching to it so both lists are ready and injected into the controller. This all works as expected.

The **additional feature** of my questions list view is that when a user clicks a tag displayed on questions it **automatically adds this tag to favourite list** (or off of it when that tag is already part of favourite list).

Route configuration

```
...
.when({
    templateUrl: "...",
    controller: "QuestionsController as context",
    resolve: {
        tags: ["userService", function(userService) {
            return userService.getMyTags();
        }]
    }
})
.when(...)
...
```

Controller pseudo code

```
QuestionsController.prototype.markQuestions = function() {
    this.model.questions.forEach(function(q, idx) {
        // "myTags" is resolve injected dependency
        q.isFavourite = q.tags.any(myTags.favourite);
        q.isIgnored = q.tags.any(myTags.ignored);
    });
};
QuestionsController.prototype.toggleTag = function(tag) {
    var self = this;
    // change tag subscription
    tagService
        .toggleFavourite(tag)
        .then(function() {
            // re-mark questions based on the new set of tags
            self.markQuestions();
        });
};
```

### The problem

When the view displays, all questions are loaded and correctly marked as per provided tag lists. Now when a user clicks on a specific tag and that tag's favourite status gets changes my controller's dependency should get automatically updated.

**How can I do that** since my controller is already instantiated and had tag lists injected during instantiation?

I would like to avoid loading those lists manually within my controller because in that case I should do the same during instantiation and reuse the same functionality and not have it in two places (route resolve and inside controller).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as your "resolved" variable is referring to the same object used elsewhere, they are one and the same.

So, if your `userService.getMyTags` is conceptually like the following:

```
.factory("userService", function($timeout){
  var tags = [/*...*/];
  return {
     getMyTags: function(){
        return $timeout(function(){ return tags; }, 500);
     },

     addTag: function(newTag){
        tags.push(newTag);
     }
  }
});
```

Then any reference to tags anywhere would get the changes:

```
.controller("ViewCtrl", function($scope, tags){
  $scope.tags = tags; // tags is "resolved" with userService.getMyTags()
})
.controller("AddTagCtrl", function($scope, userService){
  $scope.addTag = function(newTag){
     userService.addTag(newTag); // changes will be reflected in ViewCtrl
  }
}
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hOn5uIwz0IJQapQiEYjJ?p=preview), to illustrate

Comment: I know about that but I'm trying to use cache as intended which means I invalidate existing cache and replace it with fetched data. This also requires less processing than iterating through items and changing them and adding new and removing missing ones... I might make it using splice and join though as I end up with same array but different content...

Comment: But there still stays the problem of informing the controller to mark questions when new tags are ready. It may be that I'll be able to get away with promises instead of event propagation...

Comment: I figured that you had some cloned/cached data. But there is no magic. You either iterate yourself and change the content, but not the reference. Or, you are asking Angular to "watch for changes"

Comment: Well even watching for changes only works with the same array reference unfortunately. Otherwise it wouldn't work either.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik, right, but I meant that conceptually - because you seem to have had this expectation of Angular's capability to automatically update dependecies